# Access DispatchGroup from another class

Tags: swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch, xcode8, dispatch-async

Is it possible to access a DispatchGroup from another class?
Say I have the following function in the class `Loginfunctions.swift` (with a `var loginQueue = DispatchGroup.init()` defined out of the `func`):

```
func logUserIn(emaila: String!, passworda: String!, urlPath: String!, completionHandler:@escaping (NSDictionary) -> Void)  {
     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

     let requestURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
     let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
     request.httpMethod = "POST"
     let emailtext = emaila
     let passwordtext = passworda

     let postParameters = "email="+emailtext!+"&password="+passwordtext!;
     request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: .utf8)

     DispatchGroup.enter(loginQueue)()

     //creating a task to send the post request
     let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
         data, response, error in

         if error != nil{
             print("error is \(error)")
             return;
         }

         do {
             //converting resonse to NSDictionary
             let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
             DispatchGroup.wait(self.loginQueue)()
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     completionHandler(myJSON)
                 }
         } catch {
             print(error)
         }
     }

     //executing the task
     task.resume()
     DispatchGroup.leave(self.loginQueue)()
    }
 }
```

Calling the following from another Class (`LoginViewController.swift`) results in different values for `TEMP_VAR_FOR_LOGIN` (Instance in `LoginViewController.swift`):

```
@IBAction func userLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
            self.loginFunctions.logUserIn(emaila: self.email.text, passworda: self.password.text, urlPath: "URL_PATH_WAS_ENTERED_HERE")   {
                (completionHandler) in
                self.TEMP_VAR_FOR_LOGIN = completionHandler
                print("*****************")
                print(self.TEMP_VAR_FOR_LOGIN)
            }

            print("################")
            print(TEMP_VAR_FOR_LOGIN)
}
```

The console output is

```
Some other stuff...
#################
{
}
More other stuff...
*****************
{
The Data I need : Out of the Closure
}
```

Any help where the problem is?

P.S. Rookie here ;)

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes in your usage of `DispatchGroup` here

Comment: @KrishnaCA I believe you :D Can you help me out where exactly?

Comment: Every call of `DispatchGroup.enter()` should be balanced by `DispatchGroup.leave()` when the async call is completed. You are calling `DispatchGroup.leave()` even before the task is completed here. Can you please tell me what exactly you're trying to solve here? Are you trying to use DispatchGroup.notify() somewhere? If so, where and what is the purpose?

Comment: @KrishnaCA My Intention was for the func logUserIn to check if a user exists, using the input values from the UI (and hence update the next ViewController in another code). If a user does exist then the code print(TEMP_VAR_FOR_LOGIN) out of the closure should print the values from the query result. However it is empty...

Comment: You don't even need `DispatchGroup` in this case. I will write the answer then.

Comment: The main problem I have is how to get the results of completionhandler out of the closure? (in func userLogin). The request seems to execute after the (empty) results are sent to the completionhandler.

Comment: Hi, you can check my answer. Let me know if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URLSessionTask` method itself is an async task. So, there is no need to use `DispatchGroup` here. The `logUserIn` function can be modified as below:

```
func logUserIn(emaila: String!, passworda: String!, urlPath: String!, completionHandler:@escaping (NSDictionary) -> Void)  {

    let emailtext = emaila
    let passwordtext = passworda

    let postParameters = "email="+emailtext!+"&password="+passwordtext!;

    let requestURL = URL(string: urlPath)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: .utf8)

    //creating a task to send the post request
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    let task: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }else {
            do {
                //converting resonse to NSDictionary
                let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completionHandler(myJSON)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Secondly, the way you're using `closure` here is wrong. It is used as given below:

```
var dictionaryObj:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary() //global - defined outside functions

self.logUserIn(emaila: "lal", passworda: "lal", urlPath: "lal", completionHandler: { dictionaryObj in
    self.dictionaryObj = dictionaryObj as! NSMutableDictionary
    print(dictionaryObj)
    print(self.dictionaryObj)
})
```

Comment: I love you bro. Thanks a ton! Last question: Do you know how to get the value dictionaryObj out of the closure? I tried with defining an instance and then updating the value in the closure, but since it is async that doesn't work out.

Comment: I've tried that it doesn't :/ In the closure the value is not empty, but calling print(dictionaryObj) out of the closure results in an empty dictionary

Comment: You are not supposed to try to print it just after `task.resume()` line. It is an async process. The value will be captured only after the process is completed. I think you need to read more about async methods first. Please look into these articles. http://swiftable.io/2016/06/dispatch-queues-swift-3/

Comment: Ahh that explains it. Thanks again!